# archiver/backups does not save/restore hardlinks

Tags: files, backup, hard-link, archive

I will explain what kind of hardlinks and where and why they appeared, and why to save them.

pictures on the server are saved:

```
../foto/M/ay/uZbIKBgsXr0222858001661067986M
../foto/M/ay/uZbIKBgsXr0222858001661067986O

M miniature
O original
```

In the database path to the picture

```
../foto/M/ay/uZbIKBgsXr0222858001661067986 (but it's not important here)
```

When resizing pictures, if the picture does not require resizing, then the thumbnail "creates" for the help of the hardlink.

```
private function copy_original_to_mini() {
    link($this->fullpicname_O, $this->fullpicname_M);
}
```

When archiving/extract backups of server files, hardlinks disappear.

If there were two files in the directory, then only one is exist.

What are the parameters/programs to win for saving hardlinks?

---

*Files are processed within one disk partition, on one file system.*

---

**update 2023-10-31**

```
tar -cjf server_data2023-02-02.tar.bzip2 alpe34.host.tech/ folder/
```

Comment: You do not mention what program/command is being applied for the backup.

Comment: Hard links are not special files but directory entries pointing to the same file (the same inode). There is no difference between an original and a copy, all directory entries are only references to the same file, and a backup software must be desingned in a way to handle this. See e.g. [the section about hard links in the GNU `tar` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/hard-links.html)

Comment: Also the version of the archiving tool would be good. What language is copy_original_to_mini written in ? A function called `copy_...` which does not actually copy anything is immediately suspect.

Comment: @Bodo, ok, i read.

Comment: You added a `tar` command. Which OS and which version of `tar` do you use? Create an example directory with a few files and hard links, show a recursive directory listing (`ls -laR example_dir`) in your question. Create the archive. Assuming you use the command shown in the question, show the output of `tar tvjf server_data2023-02-02.tar.bzip2`